# How can I make a song progress bar for my audio player?

Tags: html, css

I've made a simple audio player, but now I want to add a song progress bar that fills up the timeline as the song plays, this is my html:

```
 <div id="ap-timeline" onClick={this.mouseMove} ref={(timeline) => { this.timeline = timeline }}>
   <div id="ap-handle" onMouseDown={this.mouseDown} ref={(handle) => { this.handle = handle }} />
   <div id="ap-handle-circle" onMouseDown={this.mouseDown} ref={(handleCircle) => { this.handleCircle = handleCircle }} />
 </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#ap-timeline{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  width: 550px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: $audio-slider-gray;   
  margin: 0 10px;

  #ap-handle {
    background: $white;
    height: 4px;
  }

  #ap-handle-circle {
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: $white;
    transform: scale(0.25);
  }
}   
}
```

The `ap-handle` is the progress bar that I'm trying to use to fill up the timeline as the song plays.

Comment: Do you store the length of the song anywhere?

Comment: Yes! It's in the state and can be accessed through `this.state.duration` in my component (which is also where it's rendering the html)

Comment: You'll need to take the current time of the song, the duration, and normalize that to a 0-100% and apply it to your progress bar.

Comment: @Phix That makes sense, would you be able to provide an example?? For reference, I have access to the current time of the song through `this.state.currentTime` and the duration of the song through `this.state.duration`. I'm guessing you find some kind of a ratio (the percentage of the currentTime to the duration of the song). I'm not sure how to use that in the CSS though :(

Comment: I do have this ratio in my `componentDidMount` function which seems close to what you were talking about: `let ratio = this.audio.currentTime / this.audio.duration;`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not much of a react person so excuse any poor practices here:

```css
#progress-bar {
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: center left;
}
```

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.interval = null; // setInterval
    this.audioEl = new Audio(
      "https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3"
    );

    this.audioEl.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
      this.setState({
        duration: this.audioEl.duration
      });
    });

    this.state = {
      currentTime: 0,
      duration: 0
    };
  }

  playAudio() {
    this.audioEl.play();
    // requestAnimationFrame would probably be better, but 
    // for example sake we'll use setInterval
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        currentTime: this.audioEl.currentTime,
        progress: Math.ceil((this.audioEl.currentTime / this.audioEl.duration) * 100) / 100

      });
    }, 100);
  }

  stopAudio() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
    this.audioEl.pause();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.playAudio()}>Play</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.stopAudio()}>Stop</button>

        <div
          style={{ transform: `scaleX(${this.state.progress})` }}
          id="progress-bar"
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b99end?file=index.js)

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try!